# How to display custom size (using preferredContentSize) popup from a "custom" table cell (UITableViewCell)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

**Summary:** 
I am able to get a full-screen popover but NOT a custom-size popover through a button action within a custom table cell. I am able to get it working though when the button is not within a custom cell. Upon debugging it seems that when the button is within the custom table cell the delegate object of the popoverPresentationController is not being called which is the one that resizes the popover window.

**Details:**

Following is the code that works when button is outside of UITableViewCell:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import CoreGraphics

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

    // This delegate function ensures that popup size is constrained to
   // what's specified in preferredContentSize earlier.
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}

// This is triggered by a button in UIViewController.. nothing to do
// with the UITable here. This implementation works.

@IBAction func buttonpressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let sb = self.storyboard
    let vc: AnyObject! = sb!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popover")
    let pc = vc as! PopOverWindow

    pc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    pc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    // Needs to be called BEFORE we access      
    // popoverPresentationController below. Counter-intuitive but this
    // is how apple docs recommend it 
    self.present(pc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let popover = pc.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any
    popover?.delegate = self 

    let button = sender as! UIButton

    // Need both statements below so that popover knows where to be
    // tethered
    popover?.sourceView = sender as? UIView

    // the position of the popover where it's showed
    // do not use buttons.frame
    popover?.sourceRect = button.bounds

}
```

Important function here is adaptivePresentationStyle() which makes sure that the popup is not full screen.

Now, let's try to the same in a custom UITableViewCell. Biggest change here is that UITableViewCell is NOT a descendant of UIViewController

```
@IBAction func infoButtonTouchDown(sender: AnyObject) {

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let vc: AnyObject! = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popover")

    let pc = vc as! PopOverWindow        
    pc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    pc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50,100)

    // Custom View Cell is not UIViewController so I need to following
    // to be able to call presentViewController later
    // I could have also done
    //self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(..)
    // but the results were the same
    let t = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let n = t.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
    let m = n.visibleViewController as! MyTableViewController

    // Important: this needs to be called BEFORE we access
    // pc.popoverPresentationController object. Apple Docs say it.
    m.presentViewController(pc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let popover = pc.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any

    // I tried doing popover?.delegate = d to make the underlying table
    // as the delegate object but the results were same
    popover?.delegate = self

    let viewForSource = sender as! UIView
    popover?.sourceView = m.view

    // the position of the popover where it's showed
    // just some random position in view.
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,1,1) 
}
```

The TROUBLE in above code is that the delegate function adaptivePresentationStyle() is not being called and consequently I end up getting a full-screen popover and not a half-screen.

Any help is hugely appreciated!